# How do I give the apache user the rights to use the ssh key

Tags: bash, git, ssh, deployment

I found a couple of other similar questions but nothing what fits to my case. Even Dr.Google wasn't able to help me.

I'm trying to make auto deployment for my server possible.
Right no I am using this deployment script https://gist.github.com/nichtich/5290675#file-deploy-php

Thats the output right now:

```
$ echo $PWD
/www/htdocs/myUserName/myDomain.com
$ whoami
sh: /usr/bin/whoami: Permission denied
$ git pull origin master
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   deploy.php
    modified:   typo3temp/var/log/typo3_ccf2d51ec3.log

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    deploy-log.txt
    infophp.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git submodule sync
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 332: /bin/uname: Permission denied
$ git submodule update
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 332: /bin/uname: Permission denied
$ git submodule status
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 332: /bin/uname: Permission denied
$ test -e /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required && echo "system restart required"
```

So the apache user doesn't have the rights to do it.
I already created an ssh key and its working perfectly If use ssh. I think my bash script is not able to use the same ssh key for the git repo, thats why it says 'Host key verification denied'.

I am not able to use 'sudo' on the server, even when I'm connected via ssh. //It's blocked by all-inkl
How do I generate an ssh key for the apache user ? And in which directory should i save it ?
Or is it somehow possible to let apache be able to use my ssh key ?

Comment: you can specifically specify what key ssh uses `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i <absPathToKey>" git pull origin master`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @g19fanatic

But it doesn't work:

`
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa

$ git pull origin master
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: For sh/bash, that must be all one line: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=... git ...`. The `$` you showed here suggests you did `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=...` and then hit ENTER, then as a second command, ran `git ...`, which doesn't do the same thing at all (surprising sh/bash thing).

Comment: Thanks for your help @torek
Its working now